# Populate textarea from dropdown when text is long and has HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have MySQL table `templates`, which looks like:

```
template_id|template_subject|template_text
------------------------------------------
1          |some subject    |very long text with html
```

These are displayed in `<select>` dropdown and complete form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="template_id"><option></option><option value="1">some subject</option></select>
<input type="text" name="template_subject">
<textarea name="template_text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit_me" value="go">
</form>
```

When user submits form, I need to get all 3 values - id, subject, and text. Furthermore, when user selects an option I need to auto populate `<input type="text" name="template_subject">` field with `some subject` and populate `<textarea name="template_text"></textarea>` with `very long text with html`

Found many examples on this site how to populate input field with option text, and textarea with option value, but here's the problem: formatting dropdown as `<select name="template_id"><option></option><option value="very long text with html">some subject</option></select>` won't work, because `template_id` value would be missing, and writing `very long text with html` as option's value would be a very bad practice, I believe.

Looking at example,s I create a JSfiddle which seems to work partially, but once again, I don't think it's a good idea to write a long text (especially with HTML into option's value) - https://jsfiddle.net/ss050535/

How should I proceed? Using jquery, bootstrap and select2 if that matters.

Comment: How about using `template_id` as `option` value and maintain a map that store the long html values with `template_id` as key? https://jsfiddle.net/ss050535/1/

Comment: Sounds like a solution. The only possible drawback of this is that page will have tons of text/HTML code (I mean inside Javascript, where template_subject and template_text will be displayed), maybe there's some way to avoid it?

Comment: The only way to avoid it is to create additional API in the server side to return the `template_text` based on given `template_id` and call it using AJAX when user click the populate button

Comment: Thanks, thought the same...